# suggestion to organise my git repo projects

Tags: git, maven

Lets say I have following project dependencies:

```
Root <---- A <----- B1 <----  C1
           |
           | <----- B2 <----  C2
```

Their dependencies are managed by maven.

Should I create git repo for each one of them in git,  or is there any other better way?  Thanks

Comment: Are B1 and B2 branches of B and C1 and C2 branches of C ?

Comment: no,  just assume they are different projects that refer to project A

Comment: Can you make this question more specific to your use case? As it is this is really an opinion question (mono repo vs independent repos vs submodules vs...).

Comment: highly depending on the nature of project.  for example, B1 and C1 are closely related, you may make them a multi-module project (and have one Git repo for them), and, for example, `A` is by nature a separate project, then it should have its own git repo.  There is no clear answer unless we have more contextual background of your projects

Answer (score 0):

You should create a git repo for each project.

A couple basic questions that one needs to ask about this issue are:  Are any of the project in a different directory tree than any of the others?  Will any of them be released as independent project for use with any other main project than the root project.  If the answer to any of these is yes, then it should be in a repo of its own.